# How to prove this approximation of logarithm of factorial

Tags: algorithms

In other words, how to prove this equation

$$\lg{n!} = \Theta(n\lg{n})$$

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/how-do-you-prove-that-nn-is-on2

Comment: Is $\Theta$ the big O?

Comment: I'm reading Introduction of Algorithm, $\Theta$ has a different meaning with big O.

Comment: $\Theta = \mathcal{O} + \Omega$. $\mathcal{O}$ is upper bound, $\Omega$ is lower bound and $\Theta$ is tight bound (both upper and lower). For eg, $n\log n = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$ but not $\Theta(n^2)$, $n \log n = \Omega(n)$ but not $\Theta(n)$ and $n \log n = \Theta(n \log n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy part is $\log(n!) \le n \log n$, which follows from $n! \le n^n$.

The hard part is discussed in [How do you prove that $n^n$ is $O(n!^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/how-do-you-prove-that-nn-is-on2/46894#46894).

Comment: I had some trouble to go from $n^n = O(n! ^ 2)$ to $n^n = O(n!)$.

Comment: @ablmf, you take logs and go from  $n^n = O(n! ^ 2)$ to $n\log n = O(\log (n!))$.

Comment: This is the most simple proof!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
n\log \bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg) + 1 \le \log n! \le (n + 1)\log \bigg(\frac{{n + 1}}{e}\bigg) + 1.
$$
Taken from Wikipedia, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n).

EDIT: Actually it is stated in that link "Hence $\log n!$ is $\Theta (n\log n)$''.

EDIT 2: The derivation of the above result is given in the Wikipedia link (and is very elementary). Based on it, let's show that
$$
\log n! = n \log n - n + O(\log n) \;\; {\rm as}\; n \to \infty,
$$
which implies, in particular, that
$$
\log n! \sim n\log n \;\; {\rm as}\; n \to \infty
$$
(that is, $\log n! / (n\log n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$), which implies, in particular, that $\log n!$ is $\Theta (n\log n)$. So, first note that
$$
n\log n - n + 1 \le \log n! \le (n + 1)\log (n + 1) - (n + 1) + 1.
$$
Hence,
$$
n\log n - n + 1 \le \log n! \le n\log (n + 1) + \log (n + 1) - n.
$$
Next note that, since $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, 
$$
\log(n+1) - \log n = \log \bigg(\frac{{n + 1}}{n}\bigg) = \log \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\bigg),
$$
and hence
$$
\log(n+1) = \log n + \frac{1}{n} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\bigg).
$$
Now,
$$
n\log n - n + 1 \le \log n! \leq n\bigg[\log n + \frac{1}{n} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\bigg)\bigg] + \bigg[\log n + \frac{1}{n} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\bigg)\bigg] - n,
$$
hence
$$
n\log n - n + 1 \le \log n! \leq n\log n - n + \log n + O(1),
$$
and finally
$$
\log n! = n \log n - n + O(\log n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$e^x = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ implies $e^n \ge \frac{n^n}{n!}$, hence $n! \ge \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$, hence $\log n! \ge n \log n - n$. On the other hand,

$$n! \le \left( \frac{1 + 2 + ... + n}{n} \right)^n = \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^n$$

by [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), hence $\log n! \le n \log \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)$.

Comment: Isn'it $n\log n-n$ (not $n\log n-1$)?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the graph of $\log$ one immediately verifies the inequalities
$$\int_1^n\log x\ dx <\sum_{k=1}^n\log k<\int_2^{n+1}\log x\ dx\ .$$
Evaluating the integrals one gets
$$n\log n -n+1< \log(n!)<(n+1)\log(n+1)-n + c$$
with $c=1-\log 4$, and this easily implies ${\log(n!)\over n\log n}\to 1$ $(n\to\infty)$.

Comment: Nice! I'm not familiar with the $\Theta$ notation. I suspect your statement to be stronger than the one in the title. Is this correct?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard: Yes, see here for the definition of various symbols concerning asymptotic behavior:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation