# Why is $\log(n!)$ $O(n\log n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

I thought that $\log(n!)$ would be $\Omega(n \log n )$, but I read somewhere that $\log(n!) = O(n\log n)$.

Why?

Comment: $$\log n!  =\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \leq  \sum_{k=1}^n \log n$$

Comment: The two statements you give are consistent. In fact both are true.

Comment: $\log(n!)$ is actually $\Theta(n \log n )$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/how-do-you-prove-that-nn-is-on2

Comment: @lhf Indeed, $\dfrac 1 2 n \log n$ and $n \log n$ suffice.

Comment: The obvious inequalities $(n/2)^{n/2} \leq n! \leq n^n$ suffice to prove $\Theta(n \log n)$.

Comment: Here is a very simple proof that $\log (n!) = \Theta(n\log (n))$: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095472/6306190

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea to prove the claim :

$$\log n!  =\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \leq  \sum_{k=1}^n \log n=n\log n$$

The other approach would be :

$$n !\sim \frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2 \pi n}$$

From where :

$$\log n !\sim n\log n -n+\frac{1}{2} \log \pi n$$

$$\frac{\log n !}{n \log n}\sim 1-\frac 1 {\log n}+\frac{1}{2}  \frac {\log \pi n} {n \log n}$$

*Add*: You are correct. It is important to note that $\mathrm{O}$ and  $\Omega$ are not mutually exclusive. Because $n\log n$ is both $\Omega$ and $\mathrm{O}$, we say that :
$$\log n! = \Theta(n \log n)$$

Comment: Thanks! Using Stirling's Approximation like that does the trick.

Comment: It's not a big deal but a factor of $2$ is missing inside some of the logs

Answer (score 12):

By Stolz-Cezaro,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (n!)}{n \ln n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln ((n+1)!)- \ln(n!)}{(n+1) \ln (n+1)-n \ln n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln ((n+1))}{\ln (n+1)+n [\ln(n+1)- \ln n]} $$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln ((n+1))}{\ln (n+1)+ [\ln(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n]}=1 $$

Thus
$$\ln (n!) \sim n \ln n$$

This implies both big O and Omega...