# Is $\log(n!)=o(\log(n^n))$?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, factorial

This is a question from CLRS (3rd edition, Pg 61) :

I have to find out whether

> $\log(n!) = o(\log(n^n))$

( Note it is [Little-oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation))

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140961/why-is-logn-on-log-n) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn) question, I can see why $\log(n!) = O(\log(n^n))$, however, I am having hard times proving the little oh.

The answer given [here](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap03/Problems/3-2/) (CLRS Solutions - walkccc) is **No** meaning,

> $\log(n!)$ is not $o(\log(n^n))$

Why is this true? My reasoning is that $\log(n^n)$ grows faster than $\log(n!)$, i.e. $\log(n!) < c \cdot \log(n^n)$ for all $c>0, n>n_0$, right?

Comment: $$
\log n! = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log k}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\log kdt} }  \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\log tdt} }  = \int_0^n {\log tdt}  = n\log n - n
$$
or
$$
e^n  = 1 + n +  \cdots  + \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} +  \cdots  \Rightarrow e^n  \ge \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} \Rightarrow \log n! \geq n\log n - n.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. One way to see this is to notice that $n!>\left(\frac n2\right)^{n/2}$, because the $n/2$ largest factors are all at least $n/2$. (You have to be slightly more careful about what happens if $n$ is odd, but it's easy to check this works for $n>1$.)

Now this seems like a terrible bound as it is much lower than $n^n$, but when we take logs it turns out to be not that much lower. $\log(n^n)=n\log n$, and $$\log\left(\left(\frac n2\right)^{n/2}\right)=\frac{n\log n}{2}-\frac{n\log 2}{2}=n\log n\left(\frac12-\frac{\log 2}{2\log n}\right).$$
Since $\frac12-\frac{\log 2}{2\log n}\to \frac12$, we have $\log(n!)>\frac 13 \log(n^n)$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

(This bound is pretty weak, and you can get a limiting factor of $1$, instead of $1/2$, using Stirling's formula, but that isn't necessary to answer the question.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\log(n!) - \log(n^n)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \log k\right)-n\log n = n\cdot \frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac k n\right) \simeq n \int_0^1 \log x dx$$
where we identify a Riemann sum for the last step.

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

$Log \, (n!)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Log \, (k) \geq \sum\limits_{k=[\sqrt n]}^{n} Log \, (k) \geq Log [\sqrt n] (n-[\sqrt n])$. So $\lim \inf \frac  1 {n log \, n}  Log \, (n!) \geq \frac 1  2$ proving that the ratio of the left side to the right side does noe tend to $0$.