# Finding Limit of Fraction Using Integration

Tags: limits, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

Using ideas around Riemann Integration and Improper Integrals, I am looking to find
$$\large\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\root^n \of {n!}}{n}
$$
I think it is clear that the $\frac{1}{n}$ term can represent the width of each section on a partition $P_n$, which would then imply we are seeking a function on a bounded interval. Given the numerator, I am struggling to find a way to compare this to the Riemann Sum for a function.

Any hints in the right direction would  be really great! Thank you

Comment: See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221138/is-logn-o-lognn/4221149#4221149

Comment: Use Stirling's formula to determine the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately I cannot use Stirling's Formula. Using Stefan's answer I have used the continuity of log to deduce that the limit is $e^{-1}$, since the limit of the log of the expression is -1, comparing it to the integral of log from 0 to 1

Comment: Also check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89d5f8WUf1Y