# Asymptotic relation between $n^{1/3}$ and $(\log n)!$

Tags: asymptotics

What is the asymptotic relation between $n^{1/3}$ and $(\log n)!$?

I compared the graphs and of course, $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/3})=(\log n)!$. However, for a more concrete proof, I compared the $\log$ of both functions although, I am not sure if this is a correct approach (and why/why not?). What I compared, as a result were
$$\log n,~\log((\log n)!)\le n\log\log n$$
but, this is not really getting me anywhere.

I do not know how to approach such questions, help would be appreciated! For some similar problems I used the $\log$ comparison approach and ended up with correct solutions but I suspect it might be a faulty approach.

**Edit.** This questions possibly has a typo and it shouldbe $\log (n!)$ instead of $(\log n)!$. However, I am just as lost in that case.

Comment: What do you mean by $(\log n)!$? Do you mean $\log(n!)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was confused too but the question mentions $(\log n)!$. Is it possibly a typo?

Comment: It could mean $\Gamma(\log n)$ which is roughly $\frac{(\log n)^{\frac12+\log n}}n$.

Comment: @nejimban Possible, but I think it is a simpler question. I'd like the answer in case it is $\log (n!)$.

Comment: @zaira: $\log(n!)\sim n\log n$, which is of course larger than $n^{\frac13}$.

Comment: See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140961/why-is-logn-on-log-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no typo in the question, we probably need to extend the factorial with $\log(n)!=\Gamma(\log(n)+1)$. Then, using Stirling's Approximation, we have
$$
\log(n)!\sim\sqrt{2\pi\log(n)}\frac{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}{e^{\log(n)}}\tag1
$$
while
$$
n^\alpha=e^{\alpha\log(n)}\tag2
$$
Dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(n)!}{n^\alpha}
&\sim\sqrt{2\pi\log(n)}\frac{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}{e^{\log(n)(1+\alpha)}}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi\log(n)}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{e^{1+\alpha}}\right)^{\log(n)}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for any $\alpha$, $\log(n)!$ will eventually be larger than $n^\alpha$.